# Dotless + MVC + Azure has garbage instead of CSS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, dotless

I've used the Nuget to add Dotless to my Azure MVC4 project. It is not working. I've triple-checked it all and it seems to be fine. When I download the less file, this is the contents:

```
‹      ì½`I–%&/mÊ{JõJ×àt¡€`$Ø@ìÁˆÍæ’ìiG#)«*ÊeVe]f@Ìí¼÷Þ{ï½÷Þ{ï½÷º;N'÷ßÿ?\fdlöÎJÚÉž!€ªÈ?~|?"~—?ö7ø5ðü:¿Æ÷÷ÿúÀïtögüî¿ðîâŸùÅàw~ÅwþÍÿ¨ý‹ƒ?èø-·ëOú=³ÿîþ£þùÿâOùï~çâó¿ó×~ëþgòŸÌ¿þÛüžÿÜÿçÿ}¿ò?øÅÿãß/ÿü=‡þ‹åøÿ¿ïùì×,ÿ×á;ÿÎ?ýü®Ð_óOý.¿Ç/ý™ßå÷øè—þ§ÿÙÞ_ûÇ–¯þ‹ÿú¼þêŸÿ/ÿëÿ×ßðÅû¿÷âW]ÿÍÿÜEñ·?ÿ½þ÷ßý—üY¿Í?ûËÿ¾¿è¯ø]þÃÏþê?cñ”ÿão“ÿâ‡ã_öWüªÿí_®þ¼¿ì¿þ•¿É?ðoýãÍ‹ÿ°zðÿ¦ÿËçï¯þk¯þÈÿãß?ù?—?õ§õþSÿãŸøþ—ÿîgÿàïòKþ·¿ÿßÿÉývå¿øËþ“ÉpôïüÎÿáßûþoÿ÷¯óküÿ÷ÿýçÿ’ã¿éïù5~_ãÿ   ÿÿiÓÀû
```

Unfortunately it appears to not be downloading correctly. Any idea why this might be the case when adding to a Windows Azure project in the Dev environment?

Comment: Let's keep this on track, in terms of Q&A. No need to accuse Windows Azure of "hating" Dotless (I took the liberty of removing your color commentary). Rather, it would be much more valuable if you gave more detail about where, in the process, your code is downloading Dotless. For instance: Are you doing this from a startup task? Or maybe you're doing this manually?

Comment: The same project outside of Azure works just fine - exact same code. I'm not sure what you mean by "Are you doing this from a startup task? Or maybe you're doing this manually?" Dotless library is included in the project and handlers added to the web.config file.

Comment: I meant are you automating the download and installation of Dotless (through PowerShell, called from startup task) vs manually installing and then bundling the bits with your app.

Comment: Oh, I'm just adding the Nuget package to the Web role with the MVC site.

Comment: Is dotless putting anything on the event log? As I see it, it could be either an exception, which should be reported in the log, or both dotless and azure are handling compression. Try configuring dotlss to not handle compression..

Comment: (do that by adding handleWebCompression="false" attribute to the config section)

Comment: @Luke - this fixed it if you'd like to make it an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add this info to the github dotless wiki too.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm having this problem or another with less on Azure.  It runs fine locally but nothing on Azure.  I added the attribute and still no worky:   <dotless minifyCss="false" cache="true" web="false"  handleWebCompression="false"  />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the response is being gzip compressed twice.

By default dotless handles the gzip/deflate compression, but since you can switch on IIS to do this, you can disable dotless from doing it by adding the `handleWebCompression="false"` attribute to the config section node.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "run outside of Azure" - where? The VS2010 Development Server or full IIS?7

Take a look at the mime types, and handlers.

Make sure .less is mapped in the IIS7 section  and not just  section.  The former is for IIS7.

Try to get it to run under IIS Express if you don't have IIS7 installed.

There's nothing much more magical on Azure other than it's Windows Server 2008 or 2008 R2 and IIS7+.